# Android service doesn't work when I close app

Tags: android, delphi, service

I don't know what is the problem  in my code !

It's Work but service doesn't work when I close app !!! and the counter restart when start app again !!! any help
My Code :

Main :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
 System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
 FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, System.IOUtils,
 System.Android.Service, FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Memo, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
FMX.StdCtrls
;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
Button1: TButton;
Memo1: TMemo;
Button2: TButton;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
FService : TLocalServiceConnection;
public
{ Public declarations }
end;

 var
  Form1: TForm1;

 implementation

  {$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

FService := TLocalServiceConnection.Create;

  end;

 procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  FService.StartService('AndroidServer');


  end;

    end.
```

Service:

```
  unit Unit2;

   interface

       uses
     System.SysUtils,  System.Threading,
    System.Classes, System.IOUtils,
     System.Android.Service,
      AndroidApi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
    Androidapi.JNI.Os, System.Notification;

     type

        TAndroidServiceDM = class(TAndroidService)
        NotificationCenter1: TNotificationCenter;
         function AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
         const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
         procedure AndroidServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
         Procedure DoNotification;
          procedure AndroidServiceTaskRemoved(const Sender: TObject;
              const ARootIntent: JIntent);
          procedure AndroidServiceDestroy(Sender: TObject);
       private
       { Private declarations }

        public
       { Public declarations }

        end;

       var
       AndroidServiceDM: TAndroidServiceDM;

        io:Integer;
        implementation

       {%CLASSGROUP 'FMX.Controls.TControl'}

            {$R *.dfm}
            uses
           Androidapi.JNI.App;

           procedure TAndroidServiceDM.DoNotification;
            Var

      MyNotification: TNotification;



     begin


    TTask.Run(procedure
      begin

     myNotification := NotificationCenter1.CreateNotification;
      try
   MyNotification.Name := 'ServiceNotification';
   MyNotification.Title := 'Android Service Notification';
    MyNotification.AlertBody := io.ToString;
    MyNotification.FireDate := Now;
    NotificationCenter1.PresentNotification(MyNotification);
   finally
    myNotification.DisposeOf;
     end;

    tthread.Synchronize(nil,
     procedure
    begin
  end);
  end
   )  ;

   end;

    procedure TAndroidServiceDM.AndroidServiceCreate(Sender: TObject);
      var
      atask : Itask;

      begin
      io:=1;
      atask := Ttask.create(procedure()

       begin

      while true do
       begin

       begin
        sleep(5000);
        DoNotification;
        io:=io+1;
      end;

      end;

 end);

 atask.Start;




  end;

  procedure TAndroidServiceDM.AndroidServiceDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  begin

  end;

   function TAndroidServiceDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender:           TObject;
     const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
    begin
    Result := TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;

      end;



     end.
```

It's Work but service doesn't work when I close app !!! 
and the counter restart when start app again !!! 
any help

Thanks

Comment: There is no such Delphi version as XE10. There are Delphi 10 Seattle and Delphi 10.1 Berlin, neither of which are XE10.

Comment: Delphi 10 Seattle and Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Answer (score 3):

A **local** service runs in the same process as the app that starts it.  So when the app terminates, so does the service.

If you need a long running service that outlives its host app, start the service in a worker thread in the host app instead of the main thread, and call the [`Service.startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) method in the service's `onStartCommand` event.

Or, you may need to mark the service as remote instead of local in its manifest, so the service runs in its own process.  Your main app can then communicate with the service as needed, such as with Intents.

Comment: @IsamBuk There are plenty examples out there on the internet. And plenty of tutorials regarding each specific task required for this broad project. Don't expect any of us here on SO to write your project for you.

Comment: Thank You can you give me example link ? worked in  Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Comment: startForeground accepts `JNotification`, but I don't know how I can get a `JNotification` from `TNotification`.

Comment: After spending hours trying to get a simple working JNotification for the service that re-opens the application when I click it, I give up. This definitely needs a working example from embarcadero. Simple "sticky" service example doesn't cut it. You still have to start the service from a base context, you still have to do various tricks to get a foreground service (which I wasn't able to divine)

Comment: @nurettin `TNotification` is a pure Delphi RTL class, it has no relation to Android specifically and so you can't get a `JNotification` interface from it. You need to use the `TJNotification` class in Delphi's Android JNI Bridge framework instead. A simple web search took 2 seconds to find a Delphi example of `startForeground()` in a comment to this blog article: [Delphi and Android services (part 2)](http://blog.blong.com/2013/11/delphi-and-android-services-part-2.html?showComment=1408428235924#c3222993916500675041).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: Is it possiible provide some example as I'm facing trouble in [Delphi 10.3] [1].

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682474/the-android-local-service-was-stopped-after-the-application-is-closed-using-delp

Answer (score 1):

1. Create service as `Remote`
2. Start service by `AlarmManager`

Here is the code for the application that starts the service and immediately turns itself off.

```
program PlayerPowerMgr;

uses
  AndroidApi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,

  Androidapi.NativeActivity,
  Androidapi.AppGlue,
  Androidapi.JNI.Embarcadero,
  ServiceUnit in '..\PowerMgrService\ServiceUnit.pas' {DM: TAndroidService};

{$R *.res}

procedure StartService;
var
     Intent: JIntent;
     PendingIntent: JPendingIntent;
const
  ServicePackageName = 'com.embarcadero.services.PlayerPwrMgrServ';
  ApplicationPackageName = 'com.embarcadero.PlayerPowerMgr';
begin
    Intent := TJIntent.Create;
    Intent.setClassName(
      StringToJString(ApplicationPackageName),
      StringToJString(ServicePackageName)
    );
     PendingIntent := TJPendingIntent.JavaClass.getService(TAndroidHelper.Context, 1, Intent, 0);
     TAndroidHelper.AlarmManager.&set(TJAlarmManager.JavaClass.RTC_WAKEUP, 1,  PendingIntent);
end;


begin
  StartService;
  TJFMXNativeActivity.Wrap(PAndroid_app(PANativeActivity(System.DelphiActivity)^.instance)^.activity.clazz).finish;
end.
```

Naturally, with the help of the project manager, you must add the service to your application. This line will appear

```
ServiceUnit in '..\PowerMgrService\ServiceUnit.pas' {DM: TAndroidService};
```

For close application use :

```
TJFMXNativeActivity.Wrap(PAndroid_app(PANativeActivity(System.DelphiActivity)^.instance)^.activity.clazz).finish;
```

It is equivalent

```
 MainActivity.Finish
```

, but the size of the application apk will be about 10M less.

To create such an application

1) Create an application as Multi-device-application / blank-application

2) In the Project manager remove Unit1 from applicrion.

3) In Project manager select application and click "`View Source`", then insert this code

4) Add you service to application